# Неправильно работает программа для подсчёта строк

Tags: c++, visual-studio

У меня есть программа, только вот она почему-то не работает. Вот главная функция из нее. Что не так?

```
void readfile()
{
    ifstream f("text.txt", ios_base::in);
    string s;
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    cout << "Какой символ?";
    cin >> c;
    while (f){
        f >> s;
        i += (s[s.length()] == c) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    cout << "Таких строк: " << i;
    system("pause");
}
```

Она должна считать количество строк оканчивающихся на заданный символ. Она работает но не правильно. Все время пишет что 0.

Comment: Текст ошибки где?

Comment: Она должна считать количество строк оканчивающихся на заданный символ. Она работает но не правильно. Все время пишет что 0. @Athari

Comment: Старайтесь [задавать попросы правильно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Ваш комментарий, например, стоило сразу включить в формулировку вопроса.

Comment: Для начала -- `f >> s` читает не строку, а *очередное слово* (последовательность непробельных символов).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексация в C++ производится от нуля, то есть индексы находятся в диапазоне от `0` до `(N-1)`.

В вашем случае последний символ строки можно получить так:

```
s[s.length() - 1]
```

или просто (если компилятор новый):

```
s.back()
```

или для верности (чтобы проверялась доступность индекса):

```
s.at(s.size() - 1)
```

Comment: @Abyx Да, и это тоже. Кстати, индекс проверяется библиотекой? Исключение будет?

Comment: О_о, подсчитало, только вот что. Строка у меня всего 1, и заканчивается на "F", я ввожу этот символ и она выдает теперь не 0, а 2 строки. @Athari

Comment: @papalimer Вы исправили код в соответствии с рекомендацией от Abyx в комментарии под вашим вопросом?

Comment: @Athari еще нет, понял.

Comment: Кстати, при самом простом цикле чтения по словам (ТС, конечно хочет одно, но пишет-то другое) проверять, что `s` не пустое не нужно (оно **просто не может быть пустым**) / А почти весь код (теперь, думаю, уже можно) получается вообще однострочником:  `while (f >> s) i += s[s.size() - 1] == c;`

Comment: @avp Неявно складывать bool и int — это всё-таки дурной тон, и новичков такому учить не надо. :)

Comment: @Athari, ну, когда-то же они *про это* (естественно, приведение типов в языке Си) все равно узнают (если свяжут свою жизнь с программированием).